# validation for greater than 10

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i am building web application asp by using Jquery.

I am stock in validation, for example

```
myfirstnumber
<input type="number" value="F" class="1" id="myfirstnumber"/>

mysecondnumber
<input type="number" value="S" class="1" id="mysecondnumber"/>

mypercenttextbox 
<input type="percentage" value="P" class="1" id="mypercenttextbox ">
```

I need to do validation if in `mypercenttextbox` is greater than `10`.

I am using jquery for this solution

```
function ValidatePayAdjustmentFormFields(){

    var isValid = true;             

    var FirstNumVal = $("[id$="+ ctrlFirstNumVal).val();
    var SecondNumVal =  $("[id$="+ ctrlSecondNumVal).val(); 
    var percentVal= (SecondNumVal - FirstNumVal ) * (100/SecondNumVal );

    if ($.trim(percentVal) >= 10)

{
        //calling handleError from other function
        handleError("mysecondnumber" ,"your mysecondnumber is more than 10% of myfirstnumber ")

        isValid = false;

    }

}       
        return isValid;
}
```

Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement
Any kind of help and tip will be appricated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a closing curly bracket too much in your code, above the return line. (Which is, if you think of it, what the error message is telling you: the return statement occurs in an illegal place ;))